# Isolating audio foreground and converting back to audio stream using librosa

Tags: python, audio, codec, librosa

I'm trying to isolate the foreground of an audio stream and then save it as a standalone audio stream using librosa.

Starting with this seemingly [relevant example](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/auto_examples/plot_vocal_separation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-vocal-separation-py).

I have the full, foreground and background data isolated as the example does in `S_full`, `S_foreground` and `S_background` but I'm unsure as to what to do to use those as audio.

I attempted to use [librosa.istft(...)](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.istft.html) to convert those and then save that as a `.wav` file using `soundfile.write(...)` but I'm left with a file of roughly the right size but unusable(?) data.

Can anyone describe or point me at an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add relevant code that you have tried and ask specific question related to that code. Asking for opinion will likely get this question closed.

Comment: `istft()` is the right way to go. How do you call it? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

in putting together the minimal example, 
istft() with the original sampling rate does in fact work.

I'll find my bug, somewhere.
FWIW here's the working code

```
import numpy as np
import librosa
from librosa import display
import soundfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y, sr = librosa.load('audio/rb-testspeech.mp3', duration=5)
S_full, phase = librosa.magphase(librosa.stft(y))

S_filter = librosa.decompose.nn_filter(S_full,
                                       aggregate=np.median,
                                       metric='cosine',
                                       width=int(librosa.time_to_frames(2, sr=sr)))
S_filter = np.minimum(S_full, S_filter)

margin_i, margin_v = 2, 10
power = 2

mask_v = librosa.util.softmask(S_full - S_filter,
                               margin_v * S_filter,
                               power=power)

S_foreground = mask_v * S_full

full = librosa.amplitude_to_db(S_full, ref=np.max)
librosa.display.specshow(full, y_axis='log', sr=sr)

plt.title('Full spectrum')
plt.colorbar()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

print("y({}): {}".format(len(y),y))
print("sr: {}".format(sr))

full_audio = librosa.istft(S_full)
foreground_audio = librosa.istft(S_foreground)
print("full({}): {}".format(len(full_audio), full_audio))

soundfile.write('orig.WAV', y, sr) 
soundfile.write('full.WAV', full_audio, sr) 
soundfile.write('foreground.WAV', foreground_audio, sr)
```